# How do you change a value of a text box in a div only using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

Is there any way to change a value of a text box located inside a div?

```
<div class="form-group">
<input id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nick" maxlength="15" 
value="change me">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter whether is inside the dive or not:

js: document.getElementById("name").value = "John Smith";

jQuery: $("#name").val("John Smith");

Answer (score 0):

Since your input has an id, super simple. Just change the value parameter.

```
var my_text_field = document.querySelector('#name');
my_text_field.value = "New Value";
```